# Firestore scope listener to rxjava disposable (not activity)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java2

I'm adding a listener to a task returned from a firestore `get()` request

```
myQuery.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(Runnable::run) { /*does something*/ }
```

I know I can scope the listener to an activity with `addOnSuccessListener(activity, ...)` which would remove the listener when the activity stops. But, to keep my code clean I need to remove the listener myself (when the rxJava observable that wraps the request is disposed - using `emitter.setCancellable{ /*remove the listener here*/ }`).

How can I remove the listener from the task?